# How to implement an auto refetch react-query but only trigger re-rendering when the query source changes value for Shopify authenticated fetch

Tags: reactjs, authentication, rendering, shopify-app

I am looking for a way to use react-query's useQuery to implement automatic refetching while not triggering react re-rendering unless the fetch source data actually changes.

The use case for this is in Shopify authenticated fetch. I have a graphql api endpoint that requires authentication to hit. Before implementing the authentication portion, I could use apollo client's useQuery to achieve the same thing: it will poll every 0.5 second and only trigger re-rendering when there is a change in the data being queried.

However, when I switched to react-query, because that's the out-of-the-box implementation method from Shopify to use its authenticatedFetch.

Here is my attempt to implement an auto periodic refetch while preventing constant re-rendering:

```
import { useAuthenticatedFetch } from "./useAuthenticatedFetch";
import { useMemo, useRef } from "react";
import { useQuery } from "react-query";
// import { useQuery } from '@apollo/client';
import isEqual from 'lodash/isEqual';

/**
 * A hook for querying your custom app data using GraphQL.
 * @desc A thin wrapper around useAuthenticatedFetch and react-query's useQuery.
 *
 * @param {Object} options - The options for your query. Accepts 4 keys:
 *
 * 1. url: The URL to query. E.g: /graphql`
 * 2. query: The GraphQL query string.
 * 3. variables: Variables for the GraphQL query.
 * 4. reactQueryOptions: The options for `useQuery`. See: https://react-query.tanstack.com/reference/useQuery
 *
 * @returns Return value of useQuery.  See: https://react-query.tanstack.com/reference/useQuery.
 */
export const useAuthenticatedGqlQuery = ({ url, query, variables = {}, reactQueryOptions }) => {
    const authenticatedFetch = useAuthenticatedFetch();

    const previousDataRef = useRef();

    const fetch = useMemo(() => {
        return async () => {
            const response = await authenticatedFetch(url, {
                method: 'POST',
                headers: {
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                },
                body: JSON.stringify({
                    query: query,
                    variables: variables,
                }),
            });
            return response.json();
        };
    }, [url, query, JSON.stringify(variables)], previousDataRef.current);

    return useQuery([url, query, variables], fetch, {
        ...reactQueryOptions,
        refetchOnWindowFocus: false,
        refetchInterval: 500, // Refetch every 0.5 seconds
        // staleTime: Infinity, // Never invalidate the cache
        select: (newData) => {
            console.log('newData: ', newData)
            console.log('previousDataRef: ', previousDataRef.current)
            console.log('are they equal? ', isEqual(newData, previousDataRef.current))
            // If the new data is deeply equal to the previous data, return the previous data
            if (previousDataRef.current && isEqual(newData, previousDataRef.current)) {
                return previousDataRef.current;
            }
            // Otherwise, update the ref and return the new data
            previousDataRef.current = newData;
            return newData;
        },
    });
};
```

This didn't work. The component still re-renders every 0.5 seconds.

Can someone suggests me a way to achieve this? Or if this is not possible can someone confirm it for me?

Thanks!